# To where does a form in an IFRAME POST?

Tags: html, forms

I got this form inside an iframe and want to know where the post actually goes.  When I go to the network tab, it only shows the src of the iframe and not where the POST request was sent.

```
<iframe id="popupOverlay_iframe" name="popupOverlayWindow" src="/cgi-bin/admin/radio_contact.cgi?action=add&amp;member_org_id=46757"></iframe>
```

The page inside this iframe contains the following:

```
<form name="add_member" method="post" onsubmit="return submitForm(this);" _lpchecked="1">
    <label>
        <input type="text" name="email.email" id="email.email" value="" class="init_focus" placeholder="Email:">
    </label>
    <input type="hidden" name="action" id="action" value="add">
    <input type="hidden" name="step" id="step" value="email">
    <input type="hidden" name="type" id="type" value="employee">
    <input type="hidden" name="member_org_id" id="member_org_id" value="46757">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Next">
    <input type="hidden" name="redirect" id="redirect" value="https://stagemms.nationalmediacalls.com/cgi-bin/admin/radio_detail.cgi?action=show&amp;id=46757">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

On submit, the JavaScript function `submitForm` is called and its result is returned.

If `submitForm` and thus the snippet returns false, the form won't be submitted. (The JS might do it's own request.)

If `submitForm` and thus the snippet returns true, the form will be posted to the current page (`/cgi-bin/admin/radio_contact.cgi?action=add&member_org_id=46757`) because no `action` was specified.

In this situation, you should have seen something like this in your network tab:

[image: Network tab]

(`/foo.html` is url of the outside page, and `/foo.cgi?action=add&member_org_id=46757` is the url of the page in the iframe.)